# jQuery code works in jsFiddle but not on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I know it's usually an encoding error, and in fact the [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) developer debugger gives me the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

But I can't see where this error is occurring. What am I doing wrong here?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/19/

```
//User defined variables
var adjacents = 3

//Script variables
var a = 0,
    b, c;
var imgArr = [];
```

My site: http://digitalbrent.com/lab/

(I've checked the other questions with similar titles but I can't seem to find the problem in my code.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your site, there are some junk characters in the code right before the `</script>`:

```
        $('.right_slot').animate({
            opacity: 0,
            left: '+=50px'
        }, 300);
    }â€‹
</script>
```

Comment: I've been looking for that because that appeared in another question, but I don't see that anywhere in my code or in my debuggers... where did you see that? What were you using?

Comment: Firebug 1.9.1 with Firefox 11.

Comment: Could they be byte-order-markers (BOM) from any UTF-8 encoded files? Make sure you encode them _without_ the BOM.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen how do I do that?

Comment: Use an editor that will tell you what the encoding is. Notepad++ does it fairly well (it will tell you the encoding in the bottom left), you can easily change or convert the encoding from the menu at the top.

Comment: Thanks guys! I couldn't see that in netbeans so I copied and pasted to notepad++ like Frits said. Then I found that funky code and got rid of it. Thanks so much for your help! I honestly couldn't see that anywhere and I would have been banging my head against the wall for hours if not for you two!